# logger not logging to remote rsyslogd instance

Tags: networking, centos, logging, log-files, rsyslog

I am running CentOS 7.0.1406 with `rsyslogd` 7.4.7 and `logger` from util-linux 2.23.2. I have two machines connected via a switch. When I try to use logger to log from one machine to the other, nothing is logged.

When I use the `--stderr` option, nothing is echoed to `stderr`, which gives me pause. `tcpdump` shows data leaving machine A and data entering machine B.

The `rsyslogd` config on machine B is as follows:

```
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 2515
*.* /home/greg/log.log
```

In debugging mode, I am starting it with:

`rsyslogd -f /home/greg/log.conf -i /home/greg/log.pid -dn`

When I run this logger command on machine A

```
logger --tcp --stderr --port 2515 --server machineB `date`
```

I receive this output from the `rsyslogd` debugging, but no output in the log file.

```
epoll returned 1 entries
epoll push ppusr[0]: 0x7f4fb55c8470
tcpsrv: ready to process 1 event entries
tcpsrv: processing item 0, pUsr 0x7f4fb55c8470, bAbortConn
New connect on NSD 0x7f4fb55cb510.
dnscache: entry (nil) found
adding nsdpoll entry 0/0x7f4fa8002cf0, sock 8
New session created with NSD 0x7f4fa8002cf0.
doing epoll_wait for max 128 events
epoll returned 1 entries
epoll push ppusr[0]: 0x7f4fa8002cf0
tcpsrv: ready to process 1 event entries
tcpsrv: processing item 0, pUsr 0x7f4fa8002cf0, bAbortConn
netstream 0x7f4fa80033a0 with new data
doing epoll_wait for max 128 events
epoll returned 1 entries
epoll push ppusr[0]: 0x7f4fa8002cf0
tcpsrv: ready to process 1 event entries
tcpsrv: processing item 0, pUsr 0x7f4fa8002cf0, bAbortConn
netstream 0x7f4fa80033a0 with new data
removing nsdpoll entry 0/0x7f4fa8002cf0, sock 8
doing epoll_wait for max 128 events
```

**EDIT:** UDP connections work fine (when loading `imudp` and using `UDPServerRun`).

Comment: Same issue, same rsyslog output.
All TCP packets recieved by rsyslog.